# javascript preventDefault doesn't work in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to disable all links on site when login validation fails. It has to prevent situation when user does next steps in user creation wizard while username is unavailable. Unfortunately it doesn't work, all links are enabled and while login is incorrect I can move forward to the next steps. These are my scripts:

```js
$(document).on("change", "#User_UserName", function (){
    var name = $('#User_UserName').val();
    Users.Validate(name);
});

Validate: function(userName) {
    SiteLoader.LockLoader();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/User/ValidateUsername",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { userName: userName },
        complete: function() {
            SiteLoader.UnLockLoader();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (!data.valid) {
                Users.BlockNextSteps();
                $('#errorContainer').html('<div class="validation-summary-errors">' +
                    '<ul><li>Username unavailable.</li></ul></div>');
            } else {
                $('#errorContainer').html('<div class="validation-summary-ok">' +
                    '<ul><li>Username available</li></ul></div>');
            }
        }
    });
},
BlockNextSteps: function() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', handleAnchor, false);
    }

    function handleAnchor(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
},
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, use it, don't mix plain js method with jq ones...

Comment: Just to complete your task. Use javascript to replace a tag with div. When validation successful toggle that to a tag again. [Check this demo to replace tag](http://jsfiddle.net/KaXxM/light/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a handler to every link on the page. It sounds wrong.    Moreover, there can be other handlers, which can be called before `handleAnchor` - JS doesn't provide any order of handlers execution.

In general, it sounds like a terrible idea. The only link you may need to disable is "next step" button. Moreover, using JS to restrict access to any part of your website is completely useless.